# Device.OpenUri opens two tabs in browser when used in page's OnAppearing method

Tags: android, xamarin, browser, xamarin.forms, uri

When I open Android's default built-in browser it opens two tabs instead of just one.
I have a MainPage, and a Page1. In MainPage I have a button that directs user to Page1.

Page1.xaml has nothing special as it is a default XAML template.
Page1.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
{
    public Page1 ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com"));
    }
}
```

**Problem:** When I enter Page1, the default Android browser(i.e Google Chrome) opens two tabs of the website https://stackoverflow.com instead of only one.

**Update:** As I debugged I noticed that this problem only occurs if we use *Device.OpenUri* in **OnAppearing()** method, as this won't occur if used in constructor.

**Update:** I tried to use native(Android for example) mechanism through DependancyService but this didn't work too:

```
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("https://stackoverflow.com");
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, uri );
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

So I think this problem must be from Android's side not Xamarin.Forms.

**Update:** Strangely if I put a delay before opening browser as in the code below the problem no longer occurs:

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    await Task.Delay(500);
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com"));
}
```

Though it might be a temporary workaround for this problem, I hope, however, someone finds a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

> When I enter Page1, the default Android browser(i.e Google Chrome) opens two tabs of the website https://stackoverflow.com instead of only one.

I think the reason is that the `OnAppearing()` fired again after `Device.OpenUri()` get called. It should be called when you get back from the browser, but it is called earlier. The browser showed and `Page1` `OnDisappearing()` fired. After that, the second `OnAppearing()` fired.

In your workaround, the second `OnAppearing()` will be fired when you get back from the browser. but it will open the URI again.

I think you should move the code to other places, such as the `button_Clicked` or `Page1 ()`.
For example:

```
public Page1 ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    Device.OpenUri(new Uri("https://stackoverflow.com"));
}
```

Comment: Even the first time when I enter Page1 the browser opens two tabs! Actually as I placed a breakpoint in OnAppearing method all the time it's fired just once not twice. However you're right that by returning from browser the OnAppearing method will be fired again, but in my real project I have a mechanism to disable opening browser when returning to page, so that won't make a problem here.

Comment: @Vahid If you set the breakpoint after `Device.OpenUri()`, you will find it fired twice.

Comment: You're right. But that's strange for me. Why it should be fired twice? Does Device.OpenUri call OnAppearing too?

Comment: BTW, why when await Task.Delay(500) is put before Device.OpenUri(), OnAppearing is fired just once?

Comment: @Vahid I think the second `OnAppearing()` is not called by `Device.OpenUri()` . It may relate to `Navigation.PushAsync()`. If I put `Device.OpenUri()` in MainPage's `OnAppearing()` method, it doesn't have this issue. I have reported this issue on [github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2716). I will keep following to it.

Comment: Good catch!
Thanks.